# Read Image and Mask (for segmentation problem) in Tensorflow-2.0 using tf.data

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to read the image dataset for the segmentation problem (1-class) by following [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images) link. My main folder contains two folders i.e. (a) `img` (b) `mask`. `img` contains image samples and `mask` contains corresponding masks. My approach was, generate the path for image and then change the string path (i.e. img->mask). I modified the code provided [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images) which now looks as:

```
def process_path(file_path):
  file_path_str = str(file_path)
  file_path_mask = file_path_str.replace('img', 'mask') 
  # load the raw data from the file as a string
  img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
  img = decode_img(img)

  mask = tf.io.read_file(str(file_path_mask))
  mask = decode_mask(mask)
  return img, mask
```

However, when I am trying to see the size of my samples using:

```
for image, mask in labeled_ds.take(1):
  print("Image shape: ", image.numpy().shape)
  print("Mask shape: ", mask.numpy().shape)
```

I am getting the following error:

`InvalidArgumentError: NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: Tensor("arg0:0", shape=(), dtype=string) : The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
; Unknown error
     [[{{node ReadFile_1}}]] [Op:IteratorGetNextSync]`

Question: Any suggestion on how to read image and mask both from a given folder without above error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `tf.regex.replace` to rename string. So, in place of python string replacement, use:`file_path_mask = tf.regex_replace(file_path, "img", "mask")`. For TF 2.0, use `tf.strings.regex_replace`.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative workaround for a similar problem. I have 200 (`nb_of_images = 200`) grayscale images of shape (512, 512) loaded as `np.array` and 200 binary masks also of shape (512, 512) and loaded as `np.array`. Within a `for` loop, I take all the images, convert them to `EagerTensor` (with [tf.convert_to_tensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/convert_to_tensor)), cast them to `tf.float32` through the `dtype` arg, add one dimension with:

```
img = img[:, :, tf.newaxis]
```

so that my images are now `EagerTensor`s of shape (512, 512, 1), and finally I append them to an external list called `images`.

Within the same loop, I do the exact same operations for the masks and in the end I append them to an external list called `masks`.

Once the `for` loop is finished, I basically have two lists of EagerTensors, with

`len(images) == len(masks) == nb_of_images`

Lastly, I re-convert the two lists to tf.Tensor with:

```
images_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(images)  # convert list back to tf.Tensor
masks_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(masks)  # convert list back to tf.Tensor
```

and finally I create the `tf.data.Dataset` with:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((images_tf, masks_tf))  # create tf.data.Dataset
```